# Can a machine learning model contain malicious code?

Tags: attacks, machine-learning

As interest in machine learning grows, it is becoming common for people without a background in data science like myself, to grab models from sources such as HuggingFace and run them.

Now my understanding of models is quite hand-wavy. Is it a gigantic bunch of C/Python code in a pickle-like format?

Again from a naive 'end user' perspective, I'm effectively taking a black box and running it on my machine. So leading on from that, is it possible for someone to embed a bunch of malicious code in a model?

Comment: It depends on the vulnerabilities in the software that processes the model. Just like Adobe Reader can be compromised by a malicious PDF. So, the answer is broadly, "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ML model is a set of parameters for complex functions (the model architecture). What you run is an actual implementation of these functions. In addition you need code which creates the features for the model from some input and which creates some useful output (like an image) from what the model produces.

When you download it might only be the parameters - which needs all the implementation already existing on your system. In this case there might be vulnerabilities in your local implementation which can be exploited by a specific set of parameters. The risk here is thus similar to running any third party software from an untrusted or potentially compromised source.

Or the download might contain everything, i.e. code and parameters. In this case it can of course be also malicious code. The risk here is thus similar to processing data from an untrusted source in an application which might have vulnerabilities.

Mitigation strategies against these risk are similar to what is done when dealing with software or data from an untrusted source - run it in some kind of isolated environment where it cannot compromise the rest of the system. This might be sandbox, container, virtual machine, different hardware ...

Comment: I see, that's kind of scary. Is there anything I can do to protect myself? There must be an obvious "don't run random models" but couldn't popular models get compromised... and how can I protect against this? Also let me know if I'm imagining a big deal out of a very small scenario.

Comment: @Mendhak: I've modified the question to make the risk comparable to things you already do, like download software from somewhere or process data from software (i.e. viewing PDF files, or basically viewing anything on the internet). And to show that established mitigation techniques work here too.

Comment: Not only are you presuming that the code itself is safe, just like any other software package, you are also assuming the ML model itself is trained to do something useful rather than something malicious, like give you bad information.  You have to use your judgement both in if you got it from a reputable source, and also judge after the fact if it does what you expect in a useful way.  You'd have to do the same if you hired someone for a job.

Comment: Thanks all! The isolation bit is useful, and indeed that's what I'd do with other 'black box' software I'm not sure about. Run it in a Docker container, Windows Sandbox, a VM, etc. It makes sense.

Comment: Some models nowadays come in .safetensors. The whole point of that format is to not contain any executable code, only parameters.